# Python Weird Return Issue

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a function that takes two root nodes (Binary Tree) and traverses and checks if they're identical. Here is how I got so far;

```
def inorder(p, q):
  if p and q:
    inorder(p.left, q.left)
    if p.val != q.val:
      return False
    inorder(p.right, q.right)
    return True
```

Even though when I add some printing into function I can see that **p.val** clearly not equal to **q.val** it still returns **True**. I couldn't figure it out. Is it returning twice because of the recursion stack calls?

Comment: What's the point of your recursive calls? You don't do anything with the values they return.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How about the p.val, q.val equality check?

Comment: Yep, that happens, but you will see results from your recursive calls that aren't used in the return from the top-level call.

Comment: @jonrsharpe To be honest I wanted to think simple and said if I were to check the equality of two binary tree's I think traversing them in the same fashion would help. An I also thought traversal could be done much quicker with recursive calls.

Comment: @Ali nothing is wrong about using recursion here, however, you'd better be checking the result of the sub-tree calls.

Comment: That is all fine, but you only *call* recursively, and don't *do anything* with the result, be it `True`, `False` or `"foo"`!

Comment: Thanks @bereal. I should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop if inorder() returns False, and if only one of p or q exists than return False.

```
def inorder(p, q):
  if p and q:
    if not inorder(p.left, q.left):
      return False
    if p.val != q.val:
      return False
    return inorder(p.right, q.right)
  return not p and not q
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code did not check the result of `inorder` calls for children. If `p` and `q` had same root values, you would always return `True`, even if `inorder(p.left, q.left)` returned `False`. Here is corrected code:

```
def inorder(p, q):
    if p is None and q is None:
        return True
    elif p is not None and q is not None:
        return (
            p.val == q.val 
            and inorder(p.left, q.left)
            and inorder(p.right, q.right)
        )
```

Comment: Even though this looks like a perfect answer, I'm sorry I couldn't understand. Can you give a bit of an explanation?

Comment: Is there any possible case where p is None and q is not None?

Comment: Yes. Imagine tree `p` being one node (root only) tree and `q` having both sons. Then `inorder(p.left, q.left)` call would be a case when p is None and q is not None.

Comment: Then this function returns None?

Comment: Yes, and boolean value of `None` is `False`, so everything works.